# How do I pass an F# function to a C# constructor?

Tags: f#

How do I pass an F# function to a C# constructor?

I have the following ViewModel written in F#:

```
type ViewModel(submitFn:Try.SubmitFn) as x =
   ...
```

I'm trying to instantiate this viewmodel from C#:

```
var cs_submit = FSharpFunc<ValidatedForm, FSharpResult<ProfileRequest,ValidatedForm>>.ToConverter(Try.submit);
DataContext = new ViewModel(cs_submit);
```

**Error**

Here's the error I receive:

```
> cannot convert from 'method group' to
 FSharpFunc<ValidatedForm, FSharpResult<ProfileRequest,ValidatedForm>>
```

**Appendix**

The actual F# function I'm trying to pass into C# code is the following:

```
module Try
...
type SubmitFn = ValidatedForm -> Result<Profile, ValidatedForm>

let submit : SubmitFn = 
    fun registration -> Error registration
```

Answer (score 1):

I used *FromConverter* instead of *ToConverter*:

```
var cs_submit = FSharpFunc<ValidatedForm, FSharpResult<ProfileRequest,ValidatedForm>>.FromConverter (Try.submit);
DataContext = new ViewModel(cs_submit);
```